# Node's data in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

For the moment, I save all my nodes data using UserData, but I often hear that I should use some sort of separate class. And I cant figure out how to use it. I have multiple nodes with their data, like hp, attack damage, and so on. And how would I retrieve data for the correct node? 
Any input would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommended you to use a plist.

You could create a plist file with the data you want to save, for example:
nodeType, hp, attack, etc.
When you initialise the game load the plist, read it and base on the nodeType value you can set up the node in code, for example nodeType 1 is your hero, 2 is your enemy, etc.

Comment: Oh. That's smart. But how would I associate the two? By node.name ?

Comment: @HelloimDarius names is good, you could use also the type (for example type 1 is HeroNode,etc). There are more than one way to associate it it all depends what works best for you.

Comment: Let's say I have 10 enemies (type), and I hit one enemy, how would I get exact node and taking his hp down, instead of adressing all enemy type?

Comment: In your collision detection logic or on the touch event you get reference to the exact node, it's nothing to do with plist. You can do the check what type is that node (for example isKindOfClass:EnemyNode) and if it's you know that enemy node is type 2 and you know value of hp so you can subtract the value from the exam node.

Comment: Oh I think I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your node and create your desired properties for each class. There are numerous examples on how to do this posted on SO.